# Read command line arguments in LOLCODE

Tags: file, variables, arguments, command-line-interface, lolcode

I have two files like:
  program.lol
  text.txt

Then, I would like to run the LOLCODE code passing the name of the text file as argument with some syntax like:

```
./interpreter program.lol text.txt
```

I would like to print the contents of the text file, but I do not know how to pass and read the arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for command line arguments [in the spec for v1.2.](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md). Not even in the [proposed future spec for v1.3](http://web.archive.org/web/20120420194728/http://lolcode.com/proposals/1.3/bukkit2). As such, it's not possible. Best you could do is pass in the name of the file as input, and then using GIMMEH to get the name of the file.